# How to find out if the user has enter any value in the input field in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-bootstrap

How to find out if the user has enter any value in the input field in react.

What I am trying to achieve is I would like to show a border around the card when the user enters the text/integer into one of the input fields inside that cards and does not click on the save button.

So border should be added to the card containing at least one of all the unsaved input fields and also changed input fields.

I am using dynamic form mentioned in the link below.

This is the link of how my dynamic form is structured (Sample Code):

[Example Dynamic form link](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-dynamic-form-fields-3fjbd?from-embed)

Dynamic form is a form repeater, wherein when I click on the "add a new row" button. the a new card will be added to the react page.

This new card will have a same set of fields with the same default values. when the user changes any of the input field in the card. a border needs to be added to the card. if the user clicks on the save button the input fields should be saved.

When make changes to a individual input fields of a card, that card is indeed get a border, however when I add a new card. the border for the old card with unsaved input fields is removed.

I have been trying to solve this for a week now. I am not using formik or react-hook-form. I am using react-bootstrap library.

I am finding it difficult to change the border of the card as and when the user enters data into the input field.

I am using a ternary statement to check if the fields are changed are not.

I am using a useState hook like this:

```
const [isFieldChanged, setisFieldChanged] = useState(false);
```

```
I am using handleClick function this to set useState variable:
    const handleClick = () => {
        setisFieldChanged(true);
    };
```

These are all the fields and this is how I have set the default value:

```
    const [inputFields, setInputFields] = useState([
        {
            fieldName: "",
            label: "",
            fieldSet: "",
            cardinality: 0,
            required: false,
            defaultValue: "",
            weight: 0,
        },
    ]);
```

Below is the code for ternary statement:

```
<Card
    id={`${inputField.id}`}
    className={
    isFieldChanged &&
    index !== 0 &&
    (inputFields.length) <= (index + 1) &&
    (inputField.cardinality !== 0 ||
    inputField.fieldName.length !== 0 ||
    inputField.label.length !== 0 ||
    inputField.fieldSet.length !== 0 ||
    inputField.required !== false ||
    inputField.defaultValue.length !== 0)
    ? " mt-2 border border-warning"
    : " mt-2 "
    }
>
```

For each of the form control I am adding onKeyPress to calling the handleClick function:

```
<Form.Control
    type="text"
placeholder="fieldName"
    name="fieldName"
    data-cy="name-text-field"
    value={inputField.fieldName}
    onChange={(event) => {
    handleInputChange(index, event);
    }}
    onKeyPress = {(event)=>{
    handleClick(index, event);
}
/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is two different states - one for saved and one for current data:

```
const initialState = {
    firstName: "",
    lastName: "",
    age: ""
  };
  const [savedFormData, saveData] = useState(initialState);
  const [currentFormData, setCurrentFormData] = useState(initialState);
```

Add an onChange event to your Form.Controls:

```
const handleChange = (name, value) => {
    setCurrentFormData((prev) => {
        return { ...prev, [name]: value };
    });
};

...

// in your Form.Control
onChange={(event) =>
    handleChange("firstName", event.target.value)
}
```

Define when there is unsafed data: you can compare both states with each other. It's not sufficient to just say "it's different when user typed something", because it can be deleted again, so the states are the same again:

```
 const dataUnsafed =
    JSON.stringify(savedFormData) !== JSON.stringify(currentFormData);
```

Finally, on save, you have to copy the current data state to the saved data state and call your API to persit the data:

```
 const onSave = () => {
    saveData(currentFormData);
    // Call your API here to persist your "savedFormData
  };
```

Use "dataUnsafed" to set styles on your card, here I just set a thicker border:

```
<Card className={dataUnsafed ? "border-3" : ""}>...</Card>
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/busy-architecture-7it9g9

Comment: Thanks you @Igor Gonak for answer my question. What I am trying to achieve is I would like to show a border around the card when the user enters the text/integer into one of the input fields inside that cards and does not click on the save button. As soon as the user clicks on the save button the border has to disappear. I am using dynamic form mentioned in the link below. 

This is the link of how my form is structured: 
https://codesandbox.io/s/react-dynamic-form-fields-3fjbd?from-embed

Comment: But this is exactly the behaviour I have in my codesandbox, no?

Comment: Yes, your codesandbox  is almost the correct solution , however I am finding it difficult to change the border of the card with the dynamic form like it the sample code  in the codesandbox of the dynamic form.

Comment: You can't expect that people give you a 100% customized and working solution just for your special case. You didn't make the effort to provide a minimal working example to your question. How can you then expect people to work through your custom code? Please respect people's time.

So why exactly are you struggling with styling the card, having my solition? I looked into your condesandbox and you didn't even added my solution to your example.

Comment: There seems to be a misunderstanding my end. the codesandbox link that I have shared is a reference and sample code. Apologizes for the inconvenience.  I did not intend to waste your time.

Comment: I still try to understand what you try to achieve. So you have many cards with firstName and lastName - should only the current card have a border? or every card with changed data in it?

Comment: I was not expecting  100% customized and working solution. I was not aware that one could create codesandbox to showcase where there are struck. its a good learning. next when I ask, I will make sure, create my own codesandbox link and share it in the question so it help everyone's time.

Comment: You don't need to create a codesandbox to have a minimal working example. You can also just provide some code as text in your initial question, which can be then copy/pasted by helpers to every environment.

Comment: Ok,  Every card with changed data should have the border to it. I have multiple cards with many fields . 

These are the fields:

           fieldName,
            label,
            fieldSet,
            cardinality,
            required,
            defaultValue,
            weight,

I will edit the question and add the complete code to the question. so that you will understand where I am struck.

Comment: I have just edited the question and added the complete file that I am working on.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the change event listener to find out when an input has been updated.

```html
<input type="text" name="search">
```

```js
document.querySelector('input[type="text"]')
    .addEventListener("change", (e) => {
        console.log("triggered");
    })
```

Comment: This tells you *when* an input is changed, not *if* an input was changed